# I want to count how many sheets in a workbook contain the same value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-workspace

My work has a Google spreadsheet full of contact information, divided into several dozen different sheets. What I want to do is check to see *how many* other sheets contain the same data as a given cell, i.e. "this email appears on *x* number of other sheets in this workbook".

Is there a way to do this, preferably in Google Sheets?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 I'm not able to do that as it contains PII and creating sample data would take all day

Comment: Make a copy of it with mock data

Comment: That would take all day.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN({Sheet1!A:Z; Sheet2!A:Z}), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 contains '@' 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9F7kNodETLPo-dh1RHQU9Jm9rAY1khalnhbHYhjc5M/edit#gid=649311450)